# Windows CMD: Create Folders within multiple SubFolders

Tags: cmd

Ive got a Folder called "Projects" which contains about 50 SubFolders [Project 1, Project 2, etc...].
Within each SubFolder [Project 1, Project 2, etc...] I would like to create a new Folder [current year] automatically.

In the end it should look a bit like that:

```
C:⁄Projects⁄Project 1/2021
C:⁄Projects⁄Project 2/2021
C:⁄Projects⁄Project 3/2021
...
C:⁄Projects⁄Project 50/2021
```

Ive already tried `mkdir` but I couldn't figure out how to tell Windows cmd.exe to create the folder 2021 within those multiple subfolders in "Projects" without addressing every single directory...

I hope some of u got an idea!

Comment: "Ive already tried mkdir but I couldn't figure out how to tell Windows cmd.exe to create the folder 2021 within those multiple subfolders in "Projects" without addressing every single directory..." You DO address each directory and you approach it with a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for /d` loop to loop over the subfolders:

```
for /d %a in ("C:\Projects\*") do md "%a\2021"
```

If you want to use it in a batchfile, use `%%a` instead of `%a`.

See `for /?` for more information.